# DeepClone not Covered in Test Class

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I have the following code to clone a lead upon specific criteria (code works, test class works, not proper coverage on trigger though):

```
private void leadDupConvert()
{    

    List<Lead> LeadsToDup = new list<Lead>(); 
    List<Lead> duplicatedLead = new list <Lead>(); 

    for( Lead myLead : (List<Lead>)Trigger.new)
    {
    Lead oldLeadDetails = ((Map<Id, Lead>)Trigger.oldMap).get(myLead.ID);        
    if(myLead.Dual_Intent__c == TRUE && myLead.IsConverted && myLead.Lead_Secondary_Owner_ID__c != NULL 
       && !oldLeadDetails.isConverted && firstRun) 
        {


            Lead newLead = myLead.clone(false, false, false, false);
            newLead.PrimeLeadID__c = myLead.id;
            newLead.Dual_Intent__c = FALSE; 
            newLead.Lead_Assigned__c = TRUE;
            newLead.Status = 'Open';
            newLead.OwnerId = myLead.Lead_Secondary_Owner_ID__c;
            newLead.Primary_Routing__c = myLead.Secondary_Routing__c;
            newLead.Secondary_Routing__c = NULL;
            newLead.Lead_Type__c = 'Existing Contact';
            newLead.ConvertedDate = NULL;
            newLead.ConvertedOpportunityId = NULL;
            newLead.ConvertedAccountId = NULL;
            newLead.IsConverted = FALSE;
            newLead.ConvertedContactId = NULL;
            newLead.Lead_Secondary_Email__c = NULL;
            newLead.Lead_Secondary_Owner__c = NULL;
            newLead.Lead_Secondary_Owner_ID__c = NULL;
        duplicatedLead.add(newLead);
        }

    }

    if(duplicatedLead.size()>0)
    {
        insert duplicatedLead;            
    }        
    firstRun = FALSE;
}
```

My test class runs properly, however I can't get proper coverage, specifically the fields are being set when the lead is cloned (newLead. fields aren't covered).

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class leadDupConvert_test {

@isTest public static  void Convert_Dual_Intent() {


Lead lea = new Lead(LastName='LeadTest',
    Company = 'TestLead',
    Lead_Type__c = 'Existing Contact',                
    Status = 'Open',
    Business_Segment__c = 'MS',
    CE_Intent_to_Purchase__c = 'B - Warm (7-12 months purchase)', //Secondary
    Intent_to_Purchase__c = 'A - Hot (0-6 months purchase)', //Primary
    Marketing_Lead_Score__c='1',
    Email = 'neededfortesting@test.com',    
    Country = 'Canada', 
    Lead_Assigned__c = False );
insert lea;

//Start leadDupConvert testing on this test lead
Database.LeadConvert le = new database.LeadConvert();
    le.setLeadId(lea.id);
    le.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(false);
    le.setConvertedStatus('Existing Opportunity');

Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(le);
    System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
    System.assert(TRUE, lea.IsConverted);
    System.Debug(lea.id + 'Converted ID');   
}
@isTest public static  void  Confirm_Dup_Lead() {    

System.test.StartTest();      

Lead ConvertedLead = [SELECT Id, OwnerID, Lead_Secondary_Owner_ID__c FROM Lead WHERE
                    isConverted = TRUE
                    ORDER BY ConvertedDate DESC LIMIT 1];

Lead dupLead = [SELECT Id, PrimeLeadID__c, OwnerID, Dual_Intent__c, Secondary_Routing__c, Lead_Type__c, ConvertedDate, ConvertedOpportunityId, 
                ConvertedAccountId, IsConverted, ConvertedContactId, 
                Lead_Secondary_Email__c, Lead_Secondary_Owner__c, Lead_Secondary_Owner_ID__c FROM Lead WHERE
                    isConverted = FALSE and PrimeLeadID__c =: ConvertedLead.ID
                    ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1]; 



System.assertNotEquals(ConvertedLead.id, dupLead.Id);
System.assertNotEquals(NULL, dupLead.Id);    
System.assertEquals(ConvertedLead.Lead_Secondary_Owner_ID__c, dupLead.OwnerID);
System.assertEquals(ConvertedLead.Id, dupLead.PrimeLeadID__c);    
System.assertEquals(False, dupLead.Dual_Intent__c);
System.assertEquals(duplead.Secondary_Routing__c, NULL);
System.assertEquals(duplead.Lead_Type__c, 'Existing Contact');
System.assertEquals(duplead.ConvertedDate, NULL);
System.assertEquals(duplead.ConvertedOpportunityId, NULL);
System.assertEquals(duplead.ConvertedAccountId, NULL);
System.assertEquals(duplead.IsConverted, FALSE);
System.assertEquals(duplead.ConvertedContactId, NULL);
System.assertEquals(duplead.Lead_Secondary_Email__c, NULL);
System.assertEquals(duplead.Lead_Secondary_Owner__c, NULL);
System.assertEquals(duplead.Lead_Secondary_Owner_ID__c, NULL);


System.test.stopTest();  
}
}
```

Comment: Neither test even calls the method, so I'm not sure how you expect to get coverage. You haven't even set up any data in your second test, and your first test doesn't even satisfy the first condition in your `if` statement (`myLead.Dual_Intent__c == TRUE`).

Comment: @Adrian, I have other code that is calculating and setting the Dual Intent flag on the Lead.  The test class runs and runs fine.  The line: System.assertEquals(ConvertedLead.Lead_Secondary_Owner_ID__c, dupLead.OwnerID);   works, along with all of the assertEquals.  My issue is getting coverage on the fields that I'm setting specifically in the class method.